# Remote logout tool

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, remote-access

I'm writing a remote log out tool for the school I attend. As system admins, we use it to log out users after our on-campus labs have closed to make sure that all the computers get updates at night. With windows 7, the tool we have now works fine. But we're updating to windows 10 for all of our machines and the tool has mysteriously stopped functioning. It's written in VB.net as of right now (open to a change to c# if needed). Currently we have 2 main functions for the program:

```vb
Private Sub LogOut()

    Dim AdminAccount As String = txtUsr.Text
    Dim AdminDomain As String = txtDomain.Text
    Dim AdminPassword As String = txtPwd.Text
    Dim ShutDownLocal As String = "c:\bin\"
    Dim LogOutProgram As String = "c:\bin\Logout.cmd"
    Dim TargetMachine As String = cboDom.Text & ComboBox1.Text & "p" & txtMachine.Text & txtDomain.Text
    Dim ShutDownCommand As String = "shutdown -t 300 /r /m \\" & TargetMachine
    If RunAs.RunAs(AdminAccount, AdminPassword, AdminDomain, ShutDownCommand, ShutDownLocal) Then
        Status.Text = "5 Minute Logout sent to machine"
    End If
End Sub
```

and

```vb
Public Shared Function RunAs(ByVal UserName As String, _
                                ByVal Password As String, _
                                ByVal DomainName As String, _
                                ByVal CommandLine As String, _
                                ByVal StartIn As String) As Boolean

    Dim iRet As Integer
    Dim si As New STARTUPINFO
    Dim pi As PROCESS_INFORMATION



    si.cb = Marshal.SizeOf(si)
    si.wShowWindow = 0

    iRet = CreateProcessWithLogonW(UserName, DomainName, Password, _
        LOGON_WITH_PROFILE, Nothing, CommandLine, _
        NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0, StartIn, si, pi)

    If iRet = 0 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Password incorrect.", "Error")
        Return False
    Else
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread)
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess)
        Return True
    End If

End Function
```

Currently this functions absolutely fine on windows 7 machines but for attempting it on windows 10 machines we either get "access denied(5)" or "The entered computer name is not valid or remote shutdown is not supported on the target computer. Check the name and then try again or contact your system administrator.(53)"

I already checked with the administrator and he said that it is enabled. We use a domain level firewall so the individual computers aren't rejecting the connection. Every machine has the same administrator groups (Which I am using the credentials for every attempt). I'm not sure of any other solutions to look into. Sorry for the wall of text, any solutions can be tested for the most part. No third party software unfortunately.

Thanks!

Comment: *Just to try it out,* you could try [PsShutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown) and see if it works (which won't help) or gives a more useful error message.